# Asp.net C# Async loading of data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

I have a simple dropdown list on an asp.net page. The data that populates the dropdown is slow to load and there isn't much I can do about it.

Instead of waiting for the data to populate and then display the page once fully loaded, I would like to display the page and maybe have a Loading... show up on the dropdown list while it loads.

What is the correct way of achieving that?

Comment: look into the await and async keywords on methods.

Comment: Lots of data will take lots of time. `async/await` won't make that go faster, they'll release the thread while waiting for the data to load. Just *don't* load data that you won't display. Use paging and/or load the data from JavaScript in pages

Comment: do ajax call from page to server to fill dropdown

Comment: It is not a huge amount of data, more like the TFS API I am using seems to be slow.

Comment: Better yet, *don't* fill the combo at all. If it takes so long to load, how are users going to work with it? Consider a solution that searches for matches as you type

Comment: @sd_dracula please explain what you *actually* want. That's a different question - if the server is slow, how do you expect reading to go faster with `async`? How about caching the items and reusing them instead of requesting them each time?

Answer (score 0):

Preform an ajax request to your controller to a specific action result that just returns the data you need to populate the dropdown.
Example:

`$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'controller/action/',
        data: { 
            arg1: 1,
            arg2: 2
        },
        success: function (data) {
            //handle the data
        }
    });
});`

`

```
public ActionResult SendDropdown(int arg1, int arg2) {
    //code to get the dropdown data
    return Json(new { dropdowndata }, JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
}
```

`